# Does Org-mode support display inline images for format like svg, gif?

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

How does Emacs display inline image for svg and gif formats in Org-mode? With `imagemagick` or something else? I know `[C-c C-x C-v]` toogle inline image display.

I found in Emacs 24.3 old version, I can inline view svg and gif images in Org-mode, but in Emacs 25.1, it can't, it will auto open `svg` and `gif` image link (`[[file:/path/to/file.gif]]`) with external program.
Does Emacs added some new options for this?

I just want Emacs can inline display support those image formats.

Found config in my init file which cause this problem:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'openwith-associations '("\\.gif\\'" "gwenview" (file)))
(add-to-list 'openwith-associations '("\\.svg\\'" "feh --magick-timeout 5" (file)))
```

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html#Handling-links):

> C-c C-x C-v     (org-toggle-inline-images)
>
> Toggle the inline display of linked images. **Normally this will only inline images that have no description part in the link**, i.e., images that will also be inlined during export. When called with a prefix argument, also display images that do have a link description. You can ask for inline images to be displayed at startup by configuring the variable org-startup-with-inline-images.

So, for images without descriptions, you can toggle inline display with `C-c C-x C-v`, and you can customize the variable `org-startup-with-inline-images` to make this the default behaviour.

This won't work for images with descriptions, but then, if you have a description you probably want that to be displayed anyways?

Comment: I know `[C-c C-x C-v]` can toggle inline image display, I want to know Why Emacs 25.1 does not show svg and gif image inline but open with external program. And how to display this two formats inline in Org-mode.

Comment: It does display svg inline for me, using Emacs 25.1.1, when I press `C-c C-x C-v` anywhere in the org buffer. It only opens the image in an external viewer if I press `return` while point is in the link, which calls `org-open-at-point`. Have you tried this with `emacs -Q`? Maybe something in your config is changing things.

Comment: I see. That must be my init config problem. I will `emacs -Q` debug. Thanks

Comment: @stardiviner have you been able to make this work? I have the same issue. Everything was working fine in Emacs 24.3, but it is not working anymore with 25.1. I am using Windows. I have the proper DLL in place, and it is still not working.

Comment: @Neoasimov I use Linux, and as I updated my question, I removed the open with association to fix this problem. Maybe you should check out that configure too. Hope this can help you.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version of the DLL, @Neoasimov? You can find out which versions Emacs wants by examining the variable `dynamic-library-alist`. The required version of some libraries was bumped up in the move from 24.5 to 25.1. (One I know for sure changed was gnutls: it was libgnutls-28.dll for 24.5 and is libgnutls-30.dll for 25.1. I don't know if any of the graphics format libraries changed as well.)